# Calculate $\alpha \sigma \alpha ^{-1}$

Tags: permutations

Exercise with permutations
$$\alpha = (12)(135), \sigma = (1579)$$
Then
$$\alpha \sigma \alpha ^{-1}= (12)(135)(1579)(531)(21)$$

In this case, I'm using permutation from right to left. I have the following steps
$$1\to 2, 2\to2, 2\to2, 2\to2, 2\to 1$$
$$2\to1, 1\to3,3\to3, 3\to1, 1\to 2$$
$$3\to1, 1\to5,5\to3, 3\to 3$$
$4$ isn't here then $4\to 4$, also $6\to 6$, $8\to 8$
$$5\to5, 5\to1, 1\to5,5\to3, 3\to 3$$
$$7\to7, 7\to7,7\to7, 9\to 9, 9\to 9$$
$$9\to9, 9\to9,9\to1, 1\to 5, 5\to 5$$
$$5\to1, 1\to5,5\to3, 3\to 3$$
Then 
$$5\to 3, 7\to 9, 9\to 5$$
but this isn't a cycle.

Comment: Permutations of that form will always have the same _cycle structure_ (as the permutation in the middle), but they wouldn't necessarily be the _same cycles_. Also, if $1 \mapsto 1$, then this corresponds to the single cycle $(1)$. What you've discovered is that you have the three one-cycles $(1)(2)(3)$ in the permutation $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}$ (though, you made a mistake in the image of $2$.

Comment: @BillWallis I've made some changes. $(1)(2)(3)(4)(6)(7)$ are one-cycles. But the number left don't cycle

Comment: $3\to3, 3\to5, 5\to 7, 7\to\to 7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\alpha \sigma \alpha ^{-1} = (1\,\,2)(1\,\,3\,\,5)(1\,\,5\,\,7\,\,9)(5\,\,3\,\,1)(2\,\,1)$. Now
$$
1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 1
$$
so $1 \mapsto 1$. Similarly
$$
2 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 7 \mapsto 7 \mapsto 7
$$
so $2 \mapsto 7$. By doing the rest of the permutations, we see that
$$
3 \mapsto 2, \,\,4 \mapsto 4, \,\,5 \mapsto 5, \,\,6 \mapsto 6, \,\,7 \mapsto 9, \,\,8 \mapsto 8, \,\,9 \mapsto 3,
$$
so to summarise we have
$$
(1)(2\,\,7\,\,9\,\,3)(4)(5)(6)(8) = (2\,\,7\,\,9\,\,3).
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hints**:

- $\alpha(i_1\:i_2\:\dots i_r)\alpha^{-1}=\bigl(\alpha(i_1)\:\alpha(i_2)\:\dots\:\alpha(i_r)\bigr)$.
- $\alpha = (1\:2)(1\:3\:5)=(1\:3\:5\:2)$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a source for a proof of the first hint? It doesn't seem trivial.

Comment: Don't believe that. It's almost obvious: $ \;\alpha^{-1}:\alpha(i_1)\mapsto i_1$ by definition of the inverse map, then $i_1\mapsto i_2$, and last $\alpha:i_2\mapsto \alpha(i_2)$ by definition.